# Create a maven property through gmaven plugin and accessing through maven-site plugin

Tags: maven, velocity, maven-site-plugin, gmaven-plugin

The sample code to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/ajorpheus/gmaven-site-test
Try doing a `mvn site:site` on that project and then looking at the `target\site\index.html`.

I want to create a property via the gmaven plugin which is accessible in a .apt.vm file parsed during maven site.

This is how I am attempting to create a maven property:

[image]

Following that, I wish to access the maven properties created above (such as `listOfFilesProp1`) in a .apt.vm file as follows :

[image]

However, the custom properties are not resolved. The inbuilt properties are resolved properly:

[image]

Would you know how to create a custom maven property through the gmaven plugin such that it is accessible in a .apt.vm file ?

Thanks !!